# Is any way to download attribute HTML5 work in IE?

Tags: html, download

Is there any way to download attribute work in IE. 
When try to force download file under IE using

Following is work fine in Firefox but not under IE

```
<a href="image.jpg" download>Click to download</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

As of now IE doesn't support download attribute, even the latest version. Some jquery plugins are available to make HTML5 tags work in IE older versions. You can give a try. Even safari also doesn't support.

You can check the full details on browsers compatibility for download attribute here

http://devble.com/set-filename-downloaded-file/

Comment: The article is not being updated. Please refer to http://caniuse.com/#feat=download for updated information.